# How can I prime aversion to conflict?

Tags: social-psychology

I'm looking for a way to prime subjects in an experiment to dislike exposure to conflict (arguments, anger between people, incivility, etc.).  Does anyone know of a good method for this?

Comment: Meier, B. P., Robinson, M. D., & Wilkowski, B. M. (2006). Turning the Other Cheek Agreeableness and the Regulation of Aggression-Related Primes. Psychological Science, 17(2), 136-142. [PDF](http://public.gettysburg.edu/~bmeier/Publications/Meier,%20Robinson,%20%26%20Wilkowski%20(2006)%20-%20Turning%20the%20other%20cheek.pdf) has some discussion of aggression primes

Comment: @JeromyAnglim Shouldn't this be an answer?

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr Okay. I've made it answer.

Answer (score 2):

Meier et al (2006). [FULL TEXT](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/7308830_Turning_the_other_cheek._Agreeableness_and_the_regulation_of_aggression-related_primes) has some discussion of aggression primes.

Meier, B. P., Robinson, M. D., & Wilkowski, B. M. (2006). Turning the Other Cheek Agreeableness and the Regulation of Aggression-Related Primes. Psychological Science, 17(2), 136-142. [FULL TEXT](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/7308830_Turning_the_other_cheek._Agreeableness_and_the_regulation_of_aggression-related_primes)

Comment: Unfortunately, the links are dead.

Comment: I've updated the link